# Why socks.socksocket() does not work function connect()

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, proxy

I have SOCKS5 proxy - 104.219.251.135:32832

```
import socks
s = socks.socksocket()
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "104.219.251.135","32832")
s.connect(("www.google.com" , 80))
```

I catch error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socks.py", line 100, in wrapper
  return function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/socks.py", line 832, in connect
   super(socksocket, self).connect(proxy_addr)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

why ? How to fix it?

How can I check the proxy for validity and know type of proxy?

Comment: Could you post the full error @Aminev Timur.

Comment: @Mr.Zeus edited

Comment: Thanks @Aminev Timur!